# How to load an image and show the image using keras?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tensorflow, keras

```
%matplotlib inline
from keras.preprocessing import image

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
img = np.random.rand(224,224,3)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

img_path = "image.jpeg"
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
print(type(img))

x = image.img_to_array(img)
print(type(x))
print(x.shape)
plt.imshow(x)
```

I have some code like this which should print the image. But it shows the image in wrong channels. What am i missing here?

Comment: "But it shows the image in wrong channels" is not a sufficient problem description. What is the outcome and how would you like to have it instead? Especially what is the role of `target_size` here, would you like to neglect colorchannels?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a image scaling issue. The input to the imshow() expects it to be in the 0-1 range, while you are passing it a [0-255] range input. Try to view it as:

```
plt.imshow(x/255.)
```

Comment: I would point that is is only true for RGB images. `plt.imshow` by default auto-scales to the range of the data given, and can be controlled by `vmin` and `vmax` parameters otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

This question is kind of old, but there is a very comfortable way to
display images:

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(image[0]).show()
```

Your image has to have 3 dimensions (if its in a batch as normally, just take desired_element). Works fine on EagerTensors or numpy arrays.