# Keras loaded png appears full black

Tags: keras, loadimage

Png file loaded by Keras appears fully black

I have a set of pngs generated from drawSvg program. They look fine when viewed in a normal image viewer like Paint. But when I load them via keras, the matplotlib imshow shows them fully black.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img,img_to_array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')

img_path = "output/L_Profile.png"
img = load_img(img_path, target_size=(100, 100))
print(type(img)) # <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>

x = img_to_array(img)
print(type(x)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(x.shape) # (100, 100, 3)
plt.imshow(x) # plt.imshow(x/255.) doesnt work either
plt.show()
```

L_Profile.png is

[image]

In matplotlib show, this appears fully black. Am I doing anything wrong?

Another issue is, the shape (100,100,3) is not what want as I need to pass this to Autoencoder Dense layer. I want this to be (100,100,1). The image ideally should be just plain black and white. I tried to convert by:

```
img = img.convert('1')
x = img_to_array(img)
print(type(x)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(x.shape) # (100, 100, 1)
plt.imshow(x) # plt.imshow(x/255.) doesnt work either
plt.show() # TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

Here plt.show() itself errors out. Not sure whats going on.

A simple workflow like opening a b&w png image into keras is not working.

Comment: why are you converting to numpy? try converting back x = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
and show that instead. consider as well the range (/255)
I mean it should accept image format not numpy.

Comment: I had referred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841869/how-to-load-an-image-and-show-the-image-using-keras ..

Comment: If I give some other color png, then the top code works, once plt.imshow(x/255.) is done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always be super-careful when using PNGs. PNGs unlike JPEGs may also have an alpha channel. Different software will assume a different background color when rendering a PNG with transparency. In your case the entire L-shape is encoded in the alpha channel and the three color channels are completely empty. Here's how the image looks in Mac's Preview app:

[image]

Notice that Preview uses a different background color and the problem becomes immediately apparent.

Also note that if you want to show a grayscale image using `imshow`, you need to squeeze the last dimension, so that the array shape becomes (100,100).

Here's how to load the alpha channel:

```py
img = load_img(img_path, color_mode='rgba', target_size=(100, 100))
print(type(img)) # <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>

x = img_to_array(img)
print(type(x)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(x.shape) # (100, 100, 4)
x = x[:,:,3]
plt.imshow(x) # plt.imshow(x/255.) doesnt work either
plt.show()
```

[image]

The colors in the image are simply the grayscale values mapped using the default color map. You can change the color map using the `cmap=` parameter of `imshow`.

Comment: This works. Thanks for the explanation and the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Using JPEG is easiest way to do it. If for example you're generating the file from a UIView in iOS use jpegData() instead of pngData()